# First iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've never programmed for an iPhone before, but have the coding experience to get by with learning Obj-C. I've been trying to come up with a good first project so that I can learn a little about the process involved with mobile development.

My idea was to make an app composed of 5 questions. Users would check off a box for each question representing "yes", "no", or "maybe", sort of like a survey. There would be a submit button at the end and the data would be sent to an email address. I figured the idea/concept was simple enough, but does anyone with iPhone experience think this is going to be too difficult to start with?

I really like the idea of creating a checklist in this first app, so any ideas related to that would be greatly appreciated. Not looking to make a usable app, just something to mess around with!

Comment: This website help you fix your problems that occur while you start programming. So you might have to start programming first.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for specific programming questions and answers.. Please read [faq..](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just messing around to learn I suggest you pick up one of the *many* iOS books. A previous SO answer will have a list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403049/best-book-resources-for-learning-ios-programming).

Usually the books start out simply and explain to you really well what you're doing. They progress to more intermediate and 'advanced' topics and tutorials throughout the books and by the end you will have touched on many of the frameworks and API needed to get started on your own ideas.

Good luck!